# How to get a key in a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

here's my list :

```
data_config = [{'music': {' extension': 'mp3'}},
 {'reports/INFOB131': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
   ' max_size': '100000',
   ' name_contains': 'INFOB131'}},
 {'reports/INFOB132': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
   ' max_size': '100000',
   ' name_contains': 'INFOB132'}},
 {'games': {' name_contains': ['SC2', 'Wesnoth']}},
 {'pictures/Namur': {' extension': 'jpeg',
   ' min_size': '5000000',
   ' name_contains': 'cercle'}},
 {'pictures/autres': {' extension': 'jpeg', ' min_size': '5000000'}}]
```

When I do these instructions, I get :

```
for i in data_config[0]['music']:
    print(data_config[0]['music'][i])

output : mp3
```

But when I do this, I get an error:

```
print(data_config[0]['music']['extension'])

output : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f71c5ad09034> in <module>()
----> 1 print(data_config[0]['music']['extension'])

KeyError: 'extension'
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: you have  blank in ' extension'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a space in your key name.  It's not extension, it's 
    " extension"

Comment: it's always the little things, isn't it?  Glad  I could spot it; it did take me a few minutes, it was easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

In a few places, you have whitespaces. To get rid of them you may want to use `.strip()`.

Comment: Thank you so much !